# Can you use MVC 2 Strongly Typed Helpers in Partial View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, strongly-typed-view, viewusercontrol

I'm trying to use the new strongly typed helpers. I've inherited the Model in my Control:
 Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl"

but intellisense isn't exposing the model and the page isn't happy with it if I force the code in. If I do it in a standard View all is good. This is what I'm expecting to be able to do:

```
<%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName) %>
```

Can these helpers be used in Partial Views in this manner?

Lloyd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

All you need to do declare your partials as strongly typed to have access to the typed Model property:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<YourModel>"
```

Comment: Thought so, why is intelli-sense not picking up my lambda then when I try m => m.FirstName? I try to type m and it completes it with mbox. Do you think it's installed v2 incorrectly or is there no intellisense support yet?